# XSD Schema Error - cvc-complex-type.2.4b: Element not allowed: settingvalue in element settinggroup

Tags: xml, apache, validation, xsd, xmlbeans

I have an issue with my XSD Schema. I keep getting the error mentioned in the title. I don't understand why it says that a certain element is not allowed in another. It doesn't complain about the `'accessrights'` but it does about the `'settingvalue'` when both of them are essentially the same (just a few basic elements; strings and booleans).

Does anyone have an idea about why it's complaining? I am using `Apache XMLBeans 3.0.1` (from the Windows 10 *CMD*) to try and validate the schema.

The XSD Schema file, in its entirety.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- Define the simple elements -->
<xs:element name="creationtime" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="customerkey" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="dependency" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="enable" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="group_id" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="groupname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="iamid" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="readonly" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="settingscategory" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="show" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="specification_id" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="valuepack" type="xs:string"/>

<!-- Define the 'accessrights' element -->
<xs:element name="accessrights">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element ref="id"/>
   <xs:element ref="show"/>
   <xs:element ref="readonly"/>
   <xs:element ref="enable"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- Define the 'settingvalue' element -->
<xs:element name="settingvalue">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element ref="id"/>
   <xs:element ref="specification_id"/>
   <xs:element ref="value"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- Define the 'settingsgroup' element -->
<xs:element name="settingsgroup">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element ref="group_id"/>
   <xs:element ref="groupname"/>
   <xs:element ref="accessrights" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element ref="settingvalue"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- Define the 'settings' element -->
<xs:element name="settings">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element ref="id"/>
   <xs:element ref="settingscategory"/>
   <xs:element ref="name"/>
   <xs:element ref="settingsgroup" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- Define the 'license' element -->
<xs:element name="license">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element ref="id"/>
   <xs:element ref="dependency" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   <xs:element ref="name"/>
   <xs:element ref="creationtime" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element ref="valuepack" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element ref="iamid" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element ref="customerkey" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element ref="description" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element ref="settings"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

An example of how an XML that conforms to the schema might look like

```
<license>
    <id>IDString</id>
    <dependency>IDStringOfOtherLicense</dependency>
    <name>LicenseName</name>
    <creationtime>2016-08-17 10:05:00</creationtime>
    <customerkey>googlemaybe</customerkey>
    <description>importantDetails</description>
    <settings>
        <id>IDString</id>
        <settingscategory>license</settingscategory>
        <name>SettingName</name>
        <settingsgroup>
            <group_id>groupIDString</group_id>
            <groupname>oldstuff</groupname>
            <settingvalue>
                <id>IDString</id>
                <specification_id>specIDString</specification_id>
                <value>true</value>
            </settingvalue>
        </settingsgroup>
    </settings>
</license>
```

Comment: The schema says "settingsgroup" but your title says "settinggroup" - is that significant. You've left out the important information for diagnosis - the instance document, and the namespace declarations in the schema.

Comment: I have updated the question to have the whole XSD file, and I have added an example XML that should fit it.

Comment: According to Saxon, this instance document is valid against this schema. Try looking carefully at how you are running the validation, e.g. are you picking up the right versions of files.

Comment: Strangely enough, it does work now. I did doublecheck it yesterday but it refused to work (I even saved the command from yesterday an copy-pasted it so I used the same today). Maybe it was some interference from Eclipse...

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM!! I designed my XSD by studying some of the over 40 XML files (licenses) that it should match, but I only looked at like 10 of them. Turns out a rare few have more than one _settingvalue_ in a single _settingsgroup_ so I just had to add a _maxOccurs="unbounded"_ there to fix it